# Which classifier to use for user recommender system

Tags: classification, recommender-system

My question may seem incorrect. If it is, mostly it is because of lack of exp.

My goal is to predict which product may user use in next month. I have a bunch of users history data. The structure is similar to this one

```
| user-id | gender | age | date    | product-1 | product-2 | product-3 |
|---------|--------|-----|---------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 12345   | 1      | 24  | 2015-04 | 0         | 1         | 0         |
| 54321   | 0      | 45  | 2015-04 | 1         | 0         | 1         |
```

Each user has a history of products he had in some particular month. Could you give any piece of advice how to preprocess my data so it will be ready for some(which one) classifier.

1. How to make data understandable for classifier so it understands that user-id is some kind of grouping value? That's the main question.
2. How to deal with absolute numbers like age or income if classifier is not a tree? Should it be fraction between 0 and 1?

Comment: One approach is to use a logistic regression since you're trying to determine binary outcomes. This type of regression model can handle inputs that are continuous (like age) or categorical (like gender). The key to ensuring it works as expected is to somehow ensure the algorithm understands that categorical data are "levels" or "factors". So it understands that 1 and 0 are not quantitative descriptions of males and females, but rather two different levels. Depending on your programming language, we can probably help you out in that regard.

Comment: Also, to be clear, the algorithm doesn't have any notion of "user-id = 12345". It only has notion of user-id 12345's *attributes*, i.e. gender, age, etc... So that's the actual input to the model, not the user-id itself. Unless of course the user-id # itself encodes some information, i.e. user-ids starting with number 1 are older than user-ids starting with 5